# I want to display complete text in TextView but some text of textView shows behind the Button

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

**In this time Button hide the text I want to show text and button separately. And also Marquee not work.i want text view proper text but in this time button hides the text of TextView**
May be its issue in Layout help me what I can do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >
</ImageView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/btn_booking"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/text_booking"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_booking"/>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually what is the issue you are facing ? Kindly be clear on it

Comment: I want to display complete text in TextView but some text of textView shows behind the Button

Comment: try using the linear layout with vertical orientation. This will solve your issue.

Comment: In this time some text show behind the button

Comment: let me know if you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >
</ImageView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/btn_booking"

    android:below = "@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/text_booking"
    android:below = "@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
  />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will help:) Don't forget to vote up

Comment: I Implement your code Onkar Nane but some Text of TextView is also on the Button.
But Marquee is work fine

Comment: Use LinearLayout with Horizontal orientation and android:weightSum = "2". put that textview and button in LinearLayout. Then use android:weight="1" for both i.e Button and TextView. Ping me once done :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >
</ImageView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/btn_booking"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/text_booking"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
   />


 </LinearLayout>
```

#### Programatically set

```
textView.setSelected(true)
```

needs to be set  for marquee to work.